# ambient definition file not picked up by typescript

Tags: typescript

I am creating [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-sheanigans-krkei) and in `./src/components/tree/index.tsx` I have this code:

```
/// <reference path="./Tree.d.ts" />

export const Tree: React.FunctionComponent<TreeProps> = ({
```

And in `Tree.d.ts` I have the interface definition:

```
export interface TreeProps<Datum, LinkComponentType, NodeComponentType> {
  top?: number;
  left?: number;
```

But tsc is complaining:

> Cannot find name 'TreeProps'.ts(2304) Exported variable 'Tree' has or
>   is using private name 'TreeProps'.ts(4025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You forgot to import the `interface` `TreeProps` from your file.

Just add the following line in your `src/components/Tree/index.tsx`

```
import {TreeProps} from './Tree'
```

**You also need to pass arguments to the Tree props**

---

Here are a few things I would like you to know, maybe you already know some things here.

1. The declaration file for the module in file `abc.js` should be in abc.d.ts, the file name should be same and should be in the same directory, or you have to explicitly add `declare module` in your declaration file.
2. Declaration files are used to tell the types of the **javascript modules**, so when you're writing typescript, you don't need to add `.d.ts` file, `tsc` will auto-generate `.js` and corresponding `.d.ts` files.

Comment: I knew about the arguments, I did not know the import would work like that for a .d.ts file.  Thanks

Comment: I'm adding a few more things you should know.

Comment: very much appreciated